System not loading default kernel on restart (RHEL 8)
I've got a weird one. I did some kernel updates. restarted, and it's still using the old kernel. I've seen an issue in the past on RHEL 7 where the default kernel sometimes fails to get updated, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. They aren't even using the last kernel, but the oldest still installed
rpm -q kernel
kernel-[oldest]
kernel-[old]
kernel-[new]
uname -r
kernel-[oldest]
grubby --default-kernel
kernel-[new]
cat /boot/grub2/grubenv
saved_entry= [...][new]
reboot
[no change to any of the above]
Comparing configs to a system that DID start using the new kernel, I haven't spotted any obvious differences.
Any ideas?

I'm not sure this is problem but run grubby --default-index and make sure the index number matches the default kernel index number. You can use grubby --info=ALL | grep -E "^kernel|^index" to get index numbers of all the kernels.

As expected, it's showing default index 0, where index 0 is the new kernel.
